# How to find roots of $f(x)=x^3-2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I find the roots of $x^3-2=0$? I have used the rational root theorem but it just isn't working, and all the methods I have used have yielded me no proper result. What do I do?

Comment: How have you used the rational root theorem? If you don't show us your attempt, your question would lack context, and also we can't figure out what conceptual issues you have (if any).

Answer (score 2):

$x^3-b^3=(x-b)(x^2+bx+b^2)$, hence $x^3-2=(x-\sqrt[3]{2})(x^2+ \sqrt[3]{2}x + 2^{\frac{2}{3}})$.

The discriminant of the quadratic is negative and hence has no real roots. However, the linear factor has a real root. Hence, the real roots of $x^3 - 2=0$ is $x=\sqrt[3]{2}$

Answer (score 2):

$$ x^3 - 2 = 0 $$
$$ x^3 = 2 $$
$$ x = 2^{\frac{1}{3}} $$

Answer (score 1):

**The rational root theorem does not work because there are no rational roots.**

When all fails, use graphing, from which you can determine the real roots of any equation (as an approximation). In this case, $x\approx 1.26$, which is a good estimate.

Here is a graph, where the parent function is $x^3$, so this function is just translated 2 units down:

[image: Roots]

Comment: How would I use synthetic division to find the other (complex) roots?

Comment: Do it as normal, with your "R" value being the cube root of 2, after which you find the roots of the depressed quadratic by applying the quadratic formula.

Comment: @mathlove because it is degree $3$ there is exactly $3$ roots and the angle between two roots is $2\pi\over 3$, and the length of the roots is the same for all roots